# How can I get COUNT to work in this query

Tags: sql, count, db2

so my goal here is to either return a 1 or a 0. I want it to return a 1 if these 2 processes have ran at the same time and a 0 if they haven't. So far, my query is able to identify if the processes had ran together, but I get an error when I try to use COUNT.

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM(
SELECT STRT_TM, END_TM
FROM TIME_TBL
WHERE PROC_NAME = 'PROC_1'
) T1
JOIN (
SELECT STRT_TM, END_TM
FROM TIME_TBL
WHERE PROC_NAME = 'PROC_2'
) T2
ON T1.STRT_TM BETWEEN T2.STRT_TM AND T2.END_TM OR T2.STRT_TM BETWEEN T1.STRT_TM AND T1.END_TM
LIMIT 1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add a numeric example.

Comment: Can be simplified .. `ON T1.STRT_TM <=  T2.END_TM AND T2.STRT_TM <= T1.END_TM`

Comment: A [mcve] is great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: something like `select smallint(count(*) > 0) from ...`

Comment: Does `LIMIT 1` exist in DB2? Are you sure you are using DB2?

Comment: @The Impaler I’m certain, and it has worked for me!

Comment: @DavidED It seems it was implemented in 11.1 (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a289729a93ffd91d5275ef8f366c4a6e). It doesn't work in 10.5.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever subselect:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT (1) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM 
(
  <YOUR_SUBSELECT_AS_IS_GOES_HERE>
) T
```